# Adding capacitor keep voltage stable

Tags: capacitor

i would like to ask if it would be problem or any recommendation. The machines have voltage drop when other machines start (big one) it would be just a few second but it effect to efficiency of this device. So
We have an idea to keep the power source stable (3phase) by adding 2 of capacitor 300uf 450V parallely at the main breaker of device. However, the device is consuming about 30amp. Not sure if the capacitor too big or too small or not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

> We have an idea to keep the power source stable (3phase)

This is AC.

You can't stabilize AC with a capacitor¹. This is literally first week of electrical engineering studies – you need to go back and refresh your basics.

---

¹ Aside from cleaning up very short transients, and you need to live with a reduced power factor if you do. But that's not what you're asking about!

Comment: Nitpick: You can't stabilize AC with a capacitor *at frequencies below the AC fundamental*; if trying to clean up spikes that are significantly shorter than a cycle, you can. That's not the case here, though.

Comment: @Hearth well said, so, see my edit :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your machines are running off of AC, adding one or more capacitors will not stabilize the voltage during the start up of one of the machines. Capacitors will stabilize a voltage for a short time if the supply is DC.

Answer (score 2):

> The machines have voltage drop when other machines start (big one)

Several general approaches are used for this, sometimes simultaneously:

1. Decrease the overload during motor startup.

   This can be done using a motor starter in the machines that cause trouble, or variable-frequency drives, etc.
2. Decrease the impedance of the supply to the machines

   This can involve replacing the transformer supplying the machines with one that has a higher power rating, so that its output impedance is lower.
3. Increase electrical separation between the machines.

   Typically this takes installing a separate supply transformer for each group of machines, to decrease the coupling by pushing transients to the higher voltage, lower current side of the transformer.

As others have stated, capacitors can't be used for this, and even if they could be used, the capacitor bank would be its own electrical load that would need calculations for the feeder size, protection, etc.